# Express js get data from api and save - buffering timed out

Tags: express, mongoose, axios

I try to get rss posts from rssapi.net and save this in database.

But when I try to save this, I have error buffering timed out. Api response works good, but database have problem to save this. When I create post in admin then save in database works fine, only don't work in this function.

Maybe someone have idea what todo.

My code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const axios = require('axios');
const { FeedItem } = require('./models/feeditem');

url = 'https://zyjswiadomie.eu/feed'

axios.get('https://api.rssapi.net/v1/83ad97e138f1d43536d5d0660da98095/get?url=' + url)
  .then(function (response) {
    const feeditems = []
    response.data.result.entries.forEach(function (item) {
        feeditems.push({
            title: item.title,
            text: item.description,
            url: item.link,
        });
        FeedItem.insertMany(feeditems)
        .then(function (docs) {
            response.json(docs);
        })
    })
})
```

My schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const FeedItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    image: { type: String, default: '' },
    title: String,
    text: String,
    url: String,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    created: Date,
    source: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Source' },
});

const FeedItem = mongoose.model('FeedItem', FeedItemSchema);

module.exports = {
    FeedItem
};
```

Traceback:

```
   (node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14380) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 4)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 5)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 6)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 8)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 9)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `feeditems.insertMany()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\macie\Documents\zyjswiadomiesocial\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
(node:14380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
(see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 10)
```

**Edit**
I add catch error, and still see buffering timed out, but I see also that mongo see object and don't save them.

This is catch error response, mongo create id for object but don't save this:

```
  insertedDocs: [
    {
      image: '',
      title: 'Moc medytacji – dowiedz się co dzięki niej zyskasz',
      text: '“Zapytano Buddę – „Co zyskałeś dzięki medytacji?” Budda odpowiedział – „Nic”. Pozwól jednak, powiedział Budda, że powiem Ci co straciłem: złość, lęk, depresję, niepewność, strach przed starością i śmiercią.” –... Artykuł Moc medytacji – dowiedz się co dzięki niej zyskasz pochodzi z serwisu Żyj świadomie.',
      url: 'https://zyjswiadomie.eu/moc-medytacji-dowiedz-sie-co-dzieki-niej-zyskasz/',
      _id: new ObjectId("629e1fc58c0b4ec34a828d7b"),
      created_at: 2022-06-06T15:39:49.799Z,
      __v: 0
    },
```

Comment: You do the `FeedItem.insertMany(feeditems)` _inside_ the `forEach`, so you insert 1 + 2 + ... + n items instead of n items.

Comment: Thank you, yes this is the problem. But it's not perfect, now it's just double save. Should save 10 posts but save 20.